# Store the data inside the operating system with Electron Js along with Angular Js

Tags: angular, electron, local-storage, electron-packager

I am building a desktop application using Angular 13. to build the desktop application I am using electron JS along with Angular 13. here I've requirement to store a data in the local system.

So I need your help like which process I need to follow to store the data in the local system. also I want to display a data inside application in a list format.

Right now i'm doing but facing an issue, please review below details
I have 1 JSON files on the client-side which are basically an array of JSON objects, from where I read and use in my component. I want to add (or edit) an object in those JSON files using angular only(without sending it to backend) and then make sure component is able to use it. Is it possible through angular? Or will I have to use a typescript file and store all information there?

I need to store the data inside the operating system as the data will be in large amount

Please if there is any other way that we can store this data in local system and show it in the application then please help me.

Thanks an advance

Comment: At this moment in time, a web-browser, including Electron's Chromium does not grant full access to the users file system. I don't believe Angular will help you in this area either. Instead, use Electron's main process (along with Node) to perform file system tasks. Doing so will also ensure your render process(es) don't freeze when trying to perform such tasks.